# Checking Redirected Product URLs

Tags: magento2, seo

After changing some product name URLs, the old URL leads to the search results page, so I created a URL rewrite, but I don't know which other Url product names have this issue, is there a tool that can help me find which URLs have been redirected? This is only the case for URLs that have been updated manually

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin Panel -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrite.`

Search under this URL which you think multiple products might have shared.

Comment: Is there a way to find it through the index coverage report on GSC? So what actually happened is that the product names were changed and URL key updated, but they did not check the create URL rewrite, so now when you click on the old link it leads to nowhere, my question is how do I find these indexed links that do not lead to the actual product

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to redirect all broken links back to the homepage instead of making it a 404, so if you want to find out which links are not being redirected, turn off the global redirect feature and see which links end up with 404 errors.

Comment: Which Magento version are you running? I don't think there is a default out-the-box Magento feature that does that. I'm guessing you use a 3rd party module to do that?